# SQL UPDATE issues

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently working on an application where an UPDATE query is performed multiple times in a row on a single table and I've stumbled into a problem.

If UPDATE query ends up swapping two rows, e.g. UPDATING 1 -> 2 and then 2 -> 1
The following happens

```
original  | 1 -> 2 | 2 -> 1 | what i want
   1      |    2   |   1    |    2
   2      |    2   |   1    |    1
   3      |    3   |   3    |    3
   4      |    4   |   4    |    4
```

There are no other columns which can be used to further differentiate the tuples consistently.
Is there a way to achieve 'what i want' without restructuring the table/database? One solution I could think of is to first delete all the rows and insert the updated ones instead (this is satisfactory implementation wise) but I'd like to know whether it's doable with an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make this one update:

```
update mytable
set col = case when col = 1 then 2 else 1 end
where col in (1,2);
```

Or three updates (by using an "impossible" value, i.e. a value that is not used in the column):

```
update mytable set col = -1 where col = 1;
update mytable set col = 1 where col = 2;
update mytable set col = 2 where col = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

u may select the ids first and put them on a two separate lists or variables to store ids then update based on that previously selected ids ?